# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 6(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{4}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1})$ converges to $6(3-4\ln(2))$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is the partial fraction decomposition of the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6}{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}$

The above series originated from the nested series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2}$

Anyways, how can I solve for the sum of this series. According to Wolfram Alpha, the sum of the series converges to $6(3-4\ln(2))$ which is around 1.364

Comment: Are you aware of the Taylor series for $\ln(1\pm x)$ and $\tan^{-1}x/\tanh^{-1}x$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{n}=2\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\,dx\\
\frac1{n+1}=2\int_{0}^1 x^{2n+1}\,dx\\
\frac4{2n+1}=4\int_{0}^1 x^{2n}\,dx$$

So $$\frac1{n}-\frac4{2n+1}+\frac1{n+1}=2\int_0^1 (1-x)^2x^{2n-1}\,dx$$

Now $$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x)^2x^{2n-1}=\frac{x(1-x)^2}{1-x^2}=2\frac{x(1-x)}{1+x}=2\left(2-x-\frac{2}{1+x}\right)$$
So the monotone converge theorem says that your series (without the $6$) can be written as $$2\int_{0}^1\frac{x(1-x)}{1+x}\,dx=3-4\ln2$$

Answer (score 1):

We will use this:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k} = -\ln 2
\tag1$$

Now, from $(1)$ we have
$$
A := \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) = 1 - \ln 2
\tag2$$
and also
$$
B := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} - \ln 2 .
\tag3$$
But then, computing $2A+2B$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{2n} - \frac{4}{2n+1}+ \frac{2}{2n+2}\right)
= 3 - 4\ln 2,
$$
which is equivalent to the required sum.